# PHP cachelite organize files into multiple directories

Tags: php, caching

I read documentation of cache_lite but couldn't found any option regarding to manage cache files into several subdirectories. Is there any addon available for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [in the constructor to cache_lite](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.caching.cache-lite.cache-lite.cache-lite.php):

Just set the `hashedDirectoryLevel` option....

```
$cache = new Cache_Lite(array('hashedDirectoryLevel' => 2));
```

Comment: Question... if I use this $cache->setLifeTime(300); $cache->save($somedata, 'key1'); $cache->setLifeTime(10000); $cache->save($anotherdata, 'key2'); $cache->setLifeTime(300); $cache->save($somedata, 'key3');  will cache_lite treat set individual lifetime for each data item?

Comment: After looking at the source, lifetime is used when garbage collected or read.  So no, you can't adjust the lifetime on a per key basis (well, you could for reading, but not for gc)...